# accessing specific values of objects nested inside an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access certain key value for objects nested inside an array.
When I try to do that with 
`filter(x => x.key('duration'));`

I get `.key is not a function.`

Here I want to access the values of keys "duration" within the objects of the array:

````js
'use strict';

const monday = [
  {
    name: 'Write a summary HTML/CSS',
    duration: 180,
  },
  {
    name: 'Some web development',
    duration: 120,
  },
  {
    name: 'Fix homework for class10',
    duration: 20,
  },
  {
    name: 'Talk to a lot of people',
    duration: 200,
  },
];

const tuesday = [
  {
    name: 'Keep writing summary',
    duration: 240,
  },
  {
    name: 'Some more web development',
    duration: 180,
  },
  {
    name: 'Staring out the window',
    duration: 10,
  },
  {
    name: 'Talk to a lot of people',
    duration: 200,
  },
  {
    name: 'Look at application assignments new students',
    duration: 40,
  },
];

const maartjesTasks = monday.concat(tuesday);
const maartjesHourlyRate = 20;
console.log(maartjesTasks);

```js
````

Comment: This is because `x.key('duration')` item "x" has no "key" method since it's an object. Just use `x.duration` or `x['duration']`.

Comment: What is expected output.

Answer (score 4):

To get the list of all duration, do not use `Array.filter` that will create a new array containing elements matching a specific condition, but `Array.map` that will create a new array containing the returned values. Here we are returning the key duration, so it creates a new array containing all duration.

Also, when using `Array.filter` or `Array.map`, the first argument of the function is the element of the array you are treating.

This element being an object, as example :

```
{
    name: 'Write a summary HTML/CSS',
    duration: 180,
},
```

The proper way to access the `duration` value is to use `.` notation, like : `x.duration`.

There is no `key` method to access an object key.

Also in my example you will see that I use of `...` which is called a `spread operator`. I use it to concatenate both arrays. It's the same as calling `concat` except that it's a lot faster.

```js
const monday = [
  {
    name: 'Write a summary HTML/CSS',
    duration: 180,
  },
  {
    name: 'Some web development',
    duration: 120,
  },
  {
    name: 'Fix homework for class10',
    duration: 20,
  },
  {
    name: 'Talk to a lot of people',
    duration: 200,
  },
];

const tuesday = [
  {
    name: 'Keep writing summary',
    duration: 240,
  },
  {
    name: 'Some more web development',
    duration: 180,
  },
  {
    name: 'Staring out the window',
    duration: 10,
  },
  {
    name: 'Talk to a lot of people',
    duration: 200,
  },
  {
    name: 'Look at application assignments new students',
    duration: 40,
  },
];

const durations = [
 ...tuesday,
 ...monday,
].map(x => x.duration);

console.log(durations);
```

---

**NOTA**: This do not handle the duplicates duration. If you wants no duplicates, I advise you to take a look at : [Set](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sets-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the object property directly with a "." like so:

```
let arr = monday.filter(obj => {
    console.log(obj.duration) // 180, 120, 20, 200 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`x.key('duration')` would call the `"key"` method of `x`, which doesn't have one.

Use *bracket notation*:

```
filter(x => x['duration']);
```

Comment: _x.key('duration') is, in fact, not valid JS._ this is not correct. It is valid js, it's just that `Object`s has no `.key` prototype, so it throws exception.

Comment: _"x.key('duration') is, in fact, not valid JS."_ Its valid JS syntax(though it will not work in this case). `x.key('duration')` is calling the method `key` of `x` with first paramter passed as a string.

Comment: @MaheerAli Agreed, bad wording. Edited.